# Why isn't it catching the exception?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I did so that only logged in users can go after clicking the button. When I'm not logged in, he throws an exception that authentication is missing. I tried this way but still throws an exception. Sorry for my english.

```cs
private async void OnMyRoutesClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new MyRoutesPage());
    }
    catch(Exception xde)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Uwaga!", "Nie masz odpowiednich uprawnień na kreatora! Skontaktuj się z administratorem", "Anuluj");
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe its not on this stack. check the stack trace?

Comment: I have already done it, thank you

Comment: Please tell us what the issue was and how did you solve it.